# jquery: checking if embedded youtube video is loaded - ready to play?

Tags: jquery, youtube

hey guys,
i've a embedded youtube video on my page.

```
<div class="vidwrapper">
    <object class="video" width="308" height="25"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/GfugtAWxooU?fs=1&amp;hl=de_DE&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="308" height="25" wmode="opaque"></embed></object>
</div>
```

my .vidwrapper has a green background and i can see that background as long as the video is not loaded onto my page.

i wonder how i could check for the moment the video is loaded onto my page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use load() to ensure the video and wrapper are loaded before displaying on the page. This will prevent the green box from showing while video is loading.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ewbN3/4/ this will ensure your video loads only after window loads.

Comment: doesn't really work! imagine that case. i want the red box only to appear when the video is loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/ewbN3/5/ -